# c# - How to get a black solid background behind button text

Tags: c#, winforms, button, text

This is the effect that I want: The text of the button having a black background.

[image]

This is how I am currently generating my button:

```
 //Button generated to add to the tab page (remmember buttons represent products)
                    Button b = new Button();

                    //Giving button appropiate size so it looks good and is suffient size to be touch screen compatible
                    b.Size = new Size(80, 80);
                    ////Giving it a better font
                    int newSize = 10;
                    //b.Font = new Font("Imperium Hollow", newSize);
                    b.ForeColor = Color.White;

                    //Displaying the Product/Buttons details on the button.
                    b.Text = row["Description"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "£" + Convert.ToDecimal(row["Price"]);
```

I fount this on the internet but I am not sure how to implement it with my code
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baw6k39s(v=vs.110).aspx

**EDIT:**

@Zohar Peled, Thanks it does the job, this is the result:

[image]

As you can see the text doesn't format itself to fit the button when I draw it I want the text to fit into a button like it does here (I still want the black background but also the formating so it fits the button.)

[image]

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Try setting `BackColor` property.

Comment: @HariPrasad BackColor will set the entire button's color, not just the text.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the OnPaint event and TextRendered to draw the text like this:

```
    private void button1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var b = sender as Button;
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, b.Text, b.Font, e.ClipRectangle, Color.White, Color.Black);
    }
```

### Update:

Use text format flags to change the way the text is displayed. Also, instead of using e.ClipRectangle, use a rectangle that is a bit smaller. (2 pixels seems to be ok in my test):

```
private void button1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var b = sender as Button;
    var rect = e.ClipRectangle;
    rect.Inflate(-2, -2);
    var flags = TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;
    switch (b.TextAlign)
    {
        case ContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter;
            break;
        case ContentAlignment.BottomLeft:
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.Bottom;
            break;
        case ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter;
            break;
            // .... add more cases
    }
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, b.Text, b.Font, rect, Color.White, Color.Black, flags);
}
```